# How to create elements and delete them with native javascript without using jQuery

Tags: javascript

In the below link, there is a add more button, i want the add more to create the same input field with a delete button associated with it, but i would like to do it all with native js if possible.

```
https://codepen.io/aazim-khaki/pen/vYZmMRq
```

Current JS :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-copy").on('click', function() {
    var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
    ele.find('input').val('')
    if (ele.find('button').length < 2) {
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
      btn.onclick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        ele.remove()
      }
      ele[0].appendChild(btn);
    }
    $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
  })
})
```

Comment: I fixed the delete. The button needed a delete class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate

I moved the form tag and gave the button a delete class

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.querySelector(".row").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains('delete')) {
      tgt.closest('.example-2').remove()
    } else if (tgt.classList.contains('btn-copy')) {
      const ele = tgt.closest(".example-2").cloneNode(true);
      ele.querySelector("input").value = "";
      if (ele.querySelectorAll("button").length < 2) {
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
        btn.classList.add("delete");
        ele.appendChild(btn);
      }
      tgt.closest(".card-body").appendChild(ele)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title">Add Class</h5>
      </div>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="example-2 form-group row">
            <!--<label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Input Addons</label>-->
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">Class Name</span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button class="btn-copy btn btn-primary" type="button">Add More</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a container and [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) so you only use one listener rather than attaching a listener to each remove button.

This is a very simple example but the principles are the same.

```js
// Cache your elements
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const add = document.querySelector('button');

// Add your container an add button listeners
container.addEventListener('click', handleEvent, false);
add.addEventListener('click', handleAdd(), false);

// If a remove button is clicked, find the
// the closest div wrapper and remove it from
// the container
function handleEvent(e) {
  const { id } = e.target.dataset;
  const row = e.target.closest('.row');
  container.removeChild(row);
}

// `handleAdd` returns a function (closure) that
// is used for the add listener rather than
// maintaining a global variable.
// We initialise the id at this point
function handleAdd(id = 0) {

  // And now return the function that will be called
  // when the add button is clicked
  // For the purposes of this example it simply adds new HTML
  // to the container, and then increases the id
  return function() {
    const html = `<div class="row"><input  value="${id}" /><button data-id="${id}">Remove</button></div>`;
    container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    ++id;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Add</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```